# Sitename is missing for Scheduled Events for Meta.SE

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, meta, chat-event

As a moderator, one of the 'powers' I have is to create and feature a chat event, which is something I distinctly remember using to 'advertise' a sitewide cleanup *years ago*.

While an RO can create events for their room, as I understand it, the moderator dialog is a little different.

On Super User, the page says:

[image: "Because you are a moderator there, an event that you schedule in this room may be advertised on superuser.com."]

On the equivalent page on MSE, the page says:

[image: "Because you are a moderator there, an event that you schedule in this room may be advertised on ."]

Now, as a moderator on Meta Stack Exchange and not a site without a name, I'm curious to whether an event I create would be advertised on MSE, not at all, or if Meta has a special scope?

Comment: Only one way to find out :)

Comment: I mean, I *could* accidentally Rickroll the entire network...